# Does Cefsharp.common vulnerability also affects Cef.sdk

Tags: cefsharp

I see this vulnerability, affecting libwebp library

https://security.snyk.io/vuln/SNYK-DOTNET-CEFSHARPCOMMON-5936337

Is this also affecting cef.sdk NuGet? - I can't see any GitHub security advise for it however I would assume that cefsharp.common and cef.sdk are both using libwebp?

Comment: CEF and CEF based projects will be effected if there is a vulnerability in Chromium. On in this case a dependency Chromium uses.